# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Getting this error, I have included the latest jquery file. Also, I have added this file in head section while I am calling jquery function in the body. Can't figure out what the problem is?

Here is my code to include jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

and jquery call is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

Error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOAsD.png)

Comment: No code, no help possible.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also note if the `$` in the error message is referring to jQuery then this has absolutely nothing to do with CodeIgniter or PHP

Comment: Thank you for editing the code in to the question. The problem is simply because the path to the jquery.js file you're using is wrong. You need to fix it. We can't tell you how, as we don't know your folder structure.

Comment: What is the result of `<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`? Maybe the jQuery file cannot be loaded.

Comment: see your console , is it loading or not

Comment: I have checked it in source code, jquery file is loading fine.

Comment: Sequence is corrent? Need first load jquery.js, then ready function.

Comment: Yes as I explained in my question. I have loaded jquery first and then loaded ready function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var $ = jQuery;

try this on top

//edit

try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: no this could also mean, jquery is in compatibility mode and does not register $ - but you are right.. i edit..

Comment: That's not working .... Same error

Comment: are you sure, jQuery is loaded? check the var jQuery

Comment: I have changed my code with one you provided. Now error is:
 Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function

Comment: seems like you are missing the $ before (document)

Comment: Thanks man.... now its working.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed newer jQueries actually launch in noConflict mode by themself, and DataTables refers to $ instead of jQuery everywhere - thus this kind of assignment is required for it to work. Awesome answer